# How to do ABI split on Gradle 3+ to change the version code?

Tags: android, gradle, google-play, abi

As per the issue raised https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64747519 and google documentation https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration#variant_api Variant API no longer works to change or alter the version code runtime.

So how can we create multiple apks and upload it to google play store?

Here's my code snippet

```
splits {
    abi {
        // Enables building multiple APKs per ABI.
        enable true

        // By default all ABIs are included, so use reset() and include to specify that we only
        // want APKs for x86, armeabi-v7a, and mips.
        reset()

        // Specifies a list of ABIs that Gradle should create APKs for.
        include "x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a"

        // Specifies that we want to also generate a universal APK that includes all ABIs.
        universalApk true
    }
}

// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
def abiCodes = ['x86': 1, 'x86_64': 2, 'armeabi-v7a': 3, 'arm64-v8a': 4]

// APKs for the same app that all have the same version information.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // Assigns a different version code for each output APK.
    variant.outputs.each {
        output ->
            def abiName = output.outputFile
            output.versionCodeOverride = abiCodes.get(abiName, 0) * 100000 + variant.versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: You seemed to get an answer on the issue tracker. Maybe you could answer your own question, as you understand it best?